# Oracle regexp n characters before and after substring excluding whitespaces

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I would like to select 10 characters before and after a particular substring from a string in oracle.
If we consider the contents of the table as:

```
with tmp as (
select 'aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeeeee' as main_text,
'xx' as sub_text
from dual
)
select * from dual;
```

I want the output to be:
`aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeee`

So I would like to exclude the spaces and count 10 to the left and 10 to the right of the substring which is 'xx'.

With spaces it is simple, but without spaces in a single query; I am not able to come up with a logic.

Experts who could help please. Using Oracle 11g :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a regular expression to do this:

```
select tmp.*,
       regexp_substr(main_text, '.{0,10}' || sub_text || '.{0,10}')
from tmp;
```

Note:  This doesn't return exactly what you specify, because this counts spaces as a character.

If you don't want to count spaces, you can ignore them as:

```
select tmp.*,
       regexp_substr(main_text, '([^ ] *){0,10}' || sub_text || '( *[^ ] *){0,10}')
from tmp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8b7014303b90ebcfd513571c419aae6) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and capturing groups to get the sub-strings before and after:

```sql
with tmp ( main_text, sub_text ) as (
  SELECT 'aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeeeee', 'xx' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.*,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         main_text,
         '((\S\s*){0,10})' || sub_text || '((\s*\S){0,10})',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS before_text,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         main_text,
         '((\S\s*){0,10})' || sub_text || '((\s*\S){0,10})',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         3
       ) AS after_text
FROM   tmp t;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MAIN_TEXT                     | SUB_TEXT | BEFORE_TEXT   | AFTER_TEXT  
> :---------------------------- | :------- | :------------ | :-----------
> aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeeeee | xx       | aa bbbb cccc  |  ddddd eeeee
> ```

And if you want to strip the spaces then:

```sql
with tmp ( main_text, sub_text ) as (
  SELECT 'aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeeeee', 'xx' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.*,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           main_text,
           '((\S\s*){0,10})' || sub_text || '((\s*\S){0,10})',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         '\s+'
       ) AS before_text,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           main_text,
           '((\S\s*){0,10})' || sub_text || '((\s*\S){0,10})',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           3
         ),
         '\s+'
       ) AS after_text
FROM   tmp t;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MAIN_TEXT                     | SUB_TEXT | BEFORE_TEXT | AFTER_TEXT
> :---------------------------- | :------- | :---------- | :---------
> aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeeeee | xx       | aabbbbcccc  | dddddeeeee
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c2580e6c55e0d0ad4f29a0f780a6d4c)*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gordon and @MT0. Using ideas from both your solutions:

```
with tmp as (
select
    'aa bbbb cccc xx ddddd eeeeeee' as main_text,
    'xx' as sub_text
from dual
)
select tmp.*,
       regexp_substr(
            main_text, 
            '(([^ ] *){0,10})' || sub_text || '(( *[^ ] *){0,10})'
       ) as plus_minus_ten,
       regexp_substr(
            main_text, 
            '(([^ ] *){0,10})' || sub_text || '(( *[^ ] *){0,10})', 
            1, 
            1, 
            NULL, 
            1 
       ) as before_sub_text,
       regexp_substr(main_text, 
            '(([^ ] *){0,10})' || sub_text || '(( *[^ ] *){0,10})', 
            1, 
            1, 
            NULL,
            3
       ) as after_sub_text
from tmp;
```